# Material Design view - how we call view like this?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, layout, material-design

What is name of a flutter view, where we have views as below - it mean top half of screen is image with additional info, and bottom half is ListView. When we scroll it, image is minimised or covered by ListView. We can find this views in a lot of apps on both systems (Android and iOS) - for example Contact info or information about album on Spotify

[image]

[image]

Comment: Collapsing Toolbar?

Comment: better use Silver widgets instead of listivews,for this design i think silver widgets is better  refer this https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/advanced/slivers and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k2v3gxtMlDE

Comment: Thank You, using Your suggestions I found solution: it is SilverAppBar, more information here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliverAppBar-class.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found solution: it is **SilverAppBar**, more information here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliverAppBar-class.html Thank You both Vasily Kabunov and Abhijith for suggestions.